# AudioServicesPlaySystemSound while AVCaptureSession is active

Tags: ios, avcapturesession, audiotoolbox

I'm developing a recording application and I want to play a sound when the recording starts.

Unfortunately it appears that since iOS 5 it's not possible to play a system sound when a `AVCaptureSession` with an audio device is active.

Here's the relevant part of the code I'm using

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURL * soundURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"recording-starts" withExtension:@"aif"];
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)soundURL, &_recStartSound);

    //...

    if ([self.captureManager setupSession]) {
        // ... 

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            [self.captureManager.session startRunning];
        });

        // ...                    
    }
}
```

Later on, I just call `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(_recStartSound)` and nothing goes on.
However if I make the same call *before* the session setup, the sound plays as expected.

I found this [bug report](http://openradar.appspot.com/10292971), which is exactly relevant to my problem, as well as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16425154/using-vibrate-and-avcapturesession-at-the-same-time) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14978840/playing-audio-file-while-recording-video-in-ios) question, but I couldn't find any workaround in none of them.

How can I play a short sound right before starting the AV recording?

Comment: Play the sound, then start the capture?

Comment: This is a very similar previous question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16309802/play-system-sound-while-recording-video-audio

Comment: can anyone please help me with this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21059607/how-to-use-vibration-while-recording-iphone5-ios

Answer (score 1):

Play the sound using AVAudioPlayer instead.

Comment: I don't understand why this is voted down. This actually works and solves what the question is asking about (play a sound while an AVCaptureSession is active).

Answer (score 0):

See [Are there any other iOS system sounds available other than 'tock'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12255164/are-there-any-other-ios-system-sounds-available-other-than-tock)

After some trial and error with system sounds available, on iOS 8.1.3 / iPhone 6 I was able to play these two:

AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1114);

and

AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1113);

**requires only one line of code to play the sound** after linking:

- AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h

  (see above link for more details)

And here's a partial-list of sounds available (from the comments in the above)
http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/AudioServices

Answer (score -1):

Extending sc0rp10n's answer, the changes to the code in the question would simply be:

Initializing the sound player (_recStartSound being of type AVAudioPlayer*):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURL * soundURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"recording-starts" withExtension:@"aif"];
    _recStartSound = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: soundURL error: NULL];

    ...
}
```

When you want to play the sound:

```
[_recStartSound play];
```